# forward a message with slack API getting invalid_blocks error

Tags: slack, slack-api, bolt

I'm trying to simply get a message from one channel and forward it to another.

all I do is listen to messages on the channel, get the blocks, i.e.:

```
[{"type":"rich_text","block_id":"AHdW3","elements":[{"type":"rich_text_section","elements":[{"type":"text","text":"z"}]}]}]
```

and send them to another channel

```
client.chat.postMessage({
    blocks: blocks,
    channel: context.targetChannel,
  });
```

I'm getting an `invalid_blocks` error, even tho this must be valid blocks since they are generated by slack themselves.

any ideas here?

I also tried to remove the `block_id` but got the same result.

I'm using bolt framework btw, but that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the blocks from 1st client slack apps are `rich_text`, which isn't supported in the api.

so the way to go is grab the `text` from the message and post that as is.

See here for context

https://github.com/slackapi/bolt-js/issues/1324